# differentiable maximum and minimum

Tags: optimization, statistics, machine-learning, calculus

I need an approximation to maximum and minimum.
Since the max and min are not differentiable I am looking for an differentiable approximation to it.

Does anybody know about it? for example I need to minimize the following:

[max (a - max_{x\in c}(x) )^2 + (a - max_{x\in d}(x) )^2]

Comment: max(a,b) = (a+b+abs(a-b))/2; min(a,b) = (a+b-abs(a-b))/2; so, just find a palatable approximation of *abs*.

Comment: I have a vector of dimension d. in that case I need a differentiable approximation to max and min.

Answer (score 2):

The [Softmax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function#Smooth_approximation_of_maximum) function is a differentiable mapping from a vector to a scalar, and approximates the maximum function.

Answer (score 1):

[Smooth maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_maximum) (and minimum) is one candidate:

```
sum(x * exp(alpha * x)) / sum(exp(alpha * x))
```

where alpha -> +Inf converges to maximum, and alpha -> -Inf to minimum.

Another is [LogSumExp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp):

```
log(sum(exp(x)))
```

Which is a max. I guess asking of a max of negated `x`s should give min

Couple of other are mentioned in paper [Multiple Instance Learning: Algorithms and Applications](http://cms.brookes.ac.uk/research/visiongroup/talks/rg_dec_11_09/bbabenko_re.pdf) such as generalized mean, noisy-or and the "ISR" model (because it's described in "Integrated segmentation and recognition" paper).